# Issue with @Cacheable annotation not working after enabling ProGuard obfuscation

Tags: java, spring, caching, proguard, obfuscation

I'm encountering an issue with the @Cacheable annotation not working properly after enabling ProGuard obfuscation in my Spring application. The caching mechanism functions correctly when ProGuard obfuscation is disabled, but as soon as I enable it, the cacheable results are not being retrieved from the cache.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = ProducerConstants.INTERFACE_CACHE, key = "#inputFolder+'-interface'", unless ="#result==null" )
List<Interface> findJobByFileNameAndPath(@Param("inputFolder") String inputFolder, @Param("active_indd") Boolean activeInd);
```

Here are the steps I have taken so far to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Verified that the inputFolder parameter has a value before it
   reaches the @Cacheable annotation by logging its value.
2. Reviewed the ProGuard configuration file and added the following rules:
   -keepattributes *Annotation*
   -keepattributes javax.persistence.* (added this line as I'm using JPA annotations alongside @Cacheable)
   -keepclassmembers class * { @org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable *; }
3. Confirmed that the ProGuard configuration file is being used during the build process.
4. Temporarily disabled other ProGuard options, such as optimization and obfuscation, to isolate the issue.
5. Checked the ProGuard output and logs for any relevant warnings or error messages.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and the cacheable results are not being retrieved after ProGuard obfuscation is enabled.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Is there anything else I need to consider in my ProGuard configuration or any alternative approaches that might better support the @Cacheable annotation in an obfuscated codebase?

**Thank you in advance for your help!**

Feel free to customize the question based on your specific scenario and provide any additional details or clarifications that you think are necessary.